# prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}$ does not converge uniformly to $e^z$ on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}$ does not converge uniformly to $e^z$ on $\mathbb{C}$?

My intuition is to assume, for a contraction, that a power series converges uniformly on $\mathbb{C}$. Then, let $$S_{m}(z) = \left(1+\frac{z}{1!}+\frac{z^{2}}{2!}+···+\frac{z^{m}}{m!}\right)−e^{z}.$$ Consider $$|S_{K+1}(z) − S_{K}(z)|$$ as $z \to \infty$ to get a contradiction.

Can I get some help in formulating the details or any other more elegant approach in this?

Comment: **HINT:**

For $z=N$, we have

$$\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}\right|\ge \frac{N^N}{N!}$$

Comment: Do you want the lower limit of the sum to be $n=0$?  Otherwise, just evaluate the sum at $0$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $S_{n}(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{m}\dfrac{z^{k}}{k!}$, if it were uniformly convergent, then for some $N$, for all $z\in{\bf{C}}$, $|S_{m}(z)-S_{n}(z)|<1$ for all $m>n\geq N$, by setting $m=N+1$ and $n=N$, then $\left|\displaystyle\dfrac{z^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}\right|<1$ for any $z\in{\bf{C}}$. Realizing $z=x>0$, then $0<\dfrac{x^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}<1$, and taking $x\rightarrow\infty$ then the expression blows up.

Comment: Hi user284331, thanks for the response. May I clarify a few Qs: I understand that the definition for uniform convergence says that $S_{n}(z) \to S(z)$ $\iff$ for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m \geq N $ implies $|S_{n}(z) - S(z)|< \epsilon \forall z \in D$. In this case, did you take $\epsilon =1$? Also, how did we establish that $|\frac{z^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}|<1$? Thanks!

Comment: So $|S_{m}(z)-S_{n}(z)|\leq|S_{m}(z)-S(z)|+|S(z)-S_{n}(z)|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

If uniformly convergent then for any $\epsilon > 0$, we have for all $m > n$ sufficiently large and all $z$

$$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{z^k}{k!}\right| < \epsilon.$$

Take $m = 2n$ and $z = (2n)^2$ and we have

$$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{z^k}{k!}\right| = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{(2n)^{2k}}{k!} \geqslant n \cdot \frac{(2n)^{2n}}{(2n)!} \to_{n \to \infty} \infty$$

Answer (score 1):

If $S_m(z)\rightarrow 0$ uniformly on $\mathbb C,$ then there is an $n$ such that $|S_n(z)|<1, z \in \mathbb C.$  Since a bounded entire function is constant, $e^z$ is a polynomial, which we know to be false.